# HTML problems with apple mail on darkmode

Tags: html, ios, macos, email, macos-darkmode

I'm having such a weird problem with a html of a mail marketing newsletter when receiving the email on apple mail (osx and ios- both latest) on dark mode. I add the media queries and everything works perfect from light to dark, images changes perfectly but theres an anoying problem with  tags.
I'm using my cta buttons as  but i cannot by any means to add a background color to the  and change ist's text color, this only on dark mode. On light everything works as it should. I send the images of the button in ligt and dark for better understanding as well my inline code and my css code. I've tried with span in text, without, with borders, with padidings, etc etc, everything i could remember. On any browser dark and light works great.
Hope someone can help me.
Many thanks

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

a.nos-button,
a.nos-button span{
       background-color: #fff !important;
        background: #fff !important;
        border-color: #fff !important;
        color: #000 !important;
   }
}


@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {

a.nos-button,
a.nos-button span{
       background-color: #000 !important;
        background: #000 !important;
        border-color: #000 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
   }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nos-button" target="_blank" style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;border-width:10px 30px;display:inline-block;background:#000000;border-radius:0px;font-family:'AzoSansWeb', arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:19px;width:auto;text-align:center"><span>COMPRE JÁ</span></a>
```

Comment: Do you have this in your <head>:

<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">